# Javascript post of json string: nothing passes in or back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm working on a page that gets data from an html table (two columns plus an index of a form) and makes a json string.  This is supposed to pass into php, then I do some calculations on the data, then send it back to the page to append the table with new column values.

Here's what I've got so far:

## Data Arrays

This is what one of the arrays looks like (LatData):

```
[1, 1, "43.07104167", "43.07178767", "43.0707977", "43.07115595", "43.06975769", "43.07023291", "43.07269194", "43.07112776", "43.07067623", "43.07285063", "43.07132924", "43.07091389", "43.07218128", "43.07279775", "43.07440354", "43.07560161", "43.07471769", "43.07073611", "43.07067713", "43.070925", "43.07148333", "43.07070833", "43.07046389", "43.07024444", "43.07127778"]
```

## Convert arrays and the int to a JSON string

So I take two arrays like the one above of the same length and the Item which is just a single value integer and I make my json string:

```
json = JSON.stringify({"Item":Item, "Lat": LatData, "Lon": LongData});
```

Then I get a nice json string as follows:

```
{"Item":1,"Lat":[1,1,"43.07104167","43.07178767","43.0707977","43.07115595","43.06975769","43.07023291","43.07269194","43.07112776","43.07067623","43.07285063","43.07132924","43.07091389","43.07218128","43.07279775","43.07440354","43.07560161","43.07471769","43.07073611","43.07067713","43.070925","43.07148333","43.07070833","43.07046389","43.07024444","43.07127778"],"Lon":[1,1,"-99.325375","-99.32837458","-99.32465527","-99.325341","-99.32509187","-99.32417542","-99.32573126","-99.32726626","-99.32830531","-99.32749062","-99.32966364","-99.32493056","-99.33109478","-99.33023795","-99.32853197","-99.32776487","-99.32631851","-99.3253","-99.32540699","-99.32571944","-99.32540278","-99.32453889","-99.32566667","-99.32622222","-99.32622222"]}
```

## Send the JSON string to PHP

Here's how I'm posting the data:

```
function MakePhpCall()
{

var json ="";  //this is the JSON string of all the data
var Item=1;    //holding this constant for now

json = JSON.stringify({"Item":Item, "Lat": LatData, "Lon": LongData});  //make JSON string to pass into PHP

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","Conversion_JQ.php?json=" + json, true);      

    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

## PHP handler

Then on the PHP side I do this:

```
$positions = json_decode($json);
echo $positions->Item[0];
echo $positions->Lat[2];
echo $positions->Lon[2];
```

I get no errors but I also don't get any call back to my div in the html page.

## Goals

Ultimately I would like to **decode the JSON to PHP arrays** and that will help me do calculations easier.

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Is your $json string in PHP equal to your json var in JavaScript ?
Are you sure the PHP is called by JavaScript (you can try with a die('Hello World'); in the PHP side

Comment: Can you try to `var_dump($positions)` and tell what you get back?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: That is probably going to be far too much data to send in the URL via GET youll probably need to use POST and send it in the body. But even if using GET was an option you would need to use `encodeUriComponent(json)` to pass it successfully.

Comment: why is `xmlhtto.open` commented? then where is json passed to php?

Comment: I'm better with javascript, but php is something I'm still learning how to diagnose these things...  I have some test text in the PHP file that do post to the html, but nothing in terms of the data I sent to php.

Comment: Sorry. That was a transcription mistake.

Comment: Where does `$json` come from? (Are you depending on the obsolete register_globals option?) Have you checked the value it has by echoing it out?

Comment: First, I would take the complete JSON and go to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to see if it's valid JSON. Sometimes even the tiniest of errors can result in the entirety of the JSON not being passed between the client/server.

Comment: @Quentin I've done this in the past using this method of sending variables to php.  I send the variable in the "xmlhttp.open("GET","Conversion_JQ.php?json=" + json, true); " and then on the PHP side I use the variable.  It's worked for me before.

Comment: @Crimpy well you would need to access it with `$_GET['json']` its not magically going to appear as `$json` for you.

Comment: @JoshBeam Ive checked the json and it is valid

Comment: Also you are doing `json_decode($json, true)` that second argument means that you are going to get associative arrays all the way through so using the `->` operator should throw a fatal error. You would wanna be doing `$positions['Item'][0]`

Comment: @prodigitalson I've written php script that I didn't have to do that and it worked, so I don't know what to say to you there. I really don't know what I'm doing other than what has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Its possible you were working in an environment that had something implemented to do that for you. I can garauntee to you that it does not work out of the box by default in `5.0 - 5.4.x`

Comment: @prodigitalson I've tried doing the json_decode both ways with and without the true and the ->. I've looked that up and both ways didn't work.

Comment: @Crimpy — You could try replying to such recommendations with "I've already tried that, the result was X" instead of "It worked before". What was the result of echoing `$json` to see if it held the value you expected?

Comment: @Quentin  I tried that as well. No result was echoed.  The only thing I can get echoed is text I put in on the php. None of the variables are working.  I tried putting in $_GET['json'] and that also didn't help get any variables in. Nothing echoed.

Comment: If I hard code `$json` to have the value you say it has, then the script echos the results I'd expect. That strongly suggests that `$json` doesn't have the value you think it does.

Comment: That's assuming you are correctly diagnosing what has been echoed (have you checked the Net tab of your browser's developer tools?) and that the problem isn't that the assignment is failing (have you checked the console for JavaScript errors?).

Comment: @Quentin I don't understand your comment about $json not having the right value that I think it does.

Comment: You said "Then I get a nice json string as follows". If I prefix your script with `$json = that string`, then the output is `43.07104167-99.325375` which means that either `$json` does not have that value or you are wrong about what the script is outputting.

Comment: As I've already said, the Javascript console has no errors. Because I'm new to PHP I am unaware of how to get the most out of the console in terms of PHP

Comment: Then look in the Net tab and examine the response as I suggested.

Comment: @prodigitalson I was able to get the string to pass in using encodeUriComponent(json). Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string was not able to be passed in using the regular method of

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","Conversion_JQ.php?json=" + json, true);
```

However, encoding the variable like this:

```
var uri = encodeRUIComponent(json);
xmlhttp.open("GET","Conversion_JQ.php?json=" + uri, true);
```

allowed the variable to pass in.  It ends up having slashes in it so I had to use

```
stripslashes($json);
```

on the PHP side to clean up the string.